# How does a FileLock work over the network? Will it only lock a local file in the mount, or will the lock "propagate" to the file on another machine?

Tags: java, spring-integration, samba, file-locking, cifs

Okay, so I'm unsure how mounts over a network work with file locks.

**This is the scenario:**

There are two JVMs, each running on a machine of its own (both Linux).

Then there is a file share, on a third machine (Windows).

Both the machines running a JVM each have mounted the same windows fileshare using CIFS/SAMBA.

If JVM-1 takes a lock on a file, using the FileLocker from Spring Integration for example, in its "local network mount" (or however to phrase it), will JVM-2 recognise that lock?

Or will the lock only be taken on that file local to the Linux machine, even though it is network share mounted and is bound somehow to a file on the Windows machine?

Comment: From looking at the `NIOFileLocker` [implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/locking/NioFileLocker.java#L46), it seems that under the hood it eventually uses `FileChannel#tryLock`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416285/java-file-locking-on-a-network) seems to suggest it won't suit your use case. (that implementation also uses an in-memory cache for locks, which would only help for multi-threaded access on a single machine)

Comment: SMB has a file-locking primitive. Why wouldn't the Java implementation use it?

Comment: What does SMB having a file-locking primitive mean? @accessviolation

Comment: And thank you @BenAnderson, I will have a look at it.

Comment: I cannot definitively answer your queestion, but: Is it possible to *avoid* this situation?  If there is one area in which "network file systems of all flavors" vary most widely, it would probably be "locking."

Comment: @MikeRobinson Ok, thanks for the heads up. I'll have that in mind when we develop this thing. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NIOFileLocker` essentially works properly only on Windows. It doesn't matter how you mount that remote Windows dir, you stil work from Linux. Moreover you said it yourself: you deal with files via SMB protocol - nothing about local filesystem where `NIOFileLocker` would have an effect.

See Spring Integration SMB support: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/smb.html#smb and consider to use an `SmbPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` based on some shared persistent DB: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/meta-data-store.html#metadata-store. The filter will look into the store to check if file has been already processed in some other instance. This is essentially a distributed file locking you are looking for.

Comment: We did indeed drop the NIOFileLocker and decided to use a FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter for this, and it seems to work.



But you mention a SmbPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter, which may be an even better fit then. I will check it out. Thanks alot.